# Pinterest dialog redirect goes wrong

Tags: user-agent, pinterest

I would like some help with the following:

I've set up sharethis at my productpages. (facebook, twitter and pinterest) and I use og-metatags for images and text witch is working fine.

Only Pinterest isn't pinning the selected image and text from the dialog.
instead of getting the success message and see my image and text show up at my pinterest page, i'm getting redirect to http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/ .

I don't now what is causing the error but maybe it is usefull to say that my site is "members only" and i made a array for the user agent/scraper of facebook. For Twitter that wasn't necessary and the user agent/scraper of pinterest i don't know.

Hope that someone will and can help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed! For Pinterest to work you need seo url's without ? & etc. signs.
The correct format is http://www.mysite.com/categorie/product/ for example.

I think this is usefull for your forum.

So if anybody get's their image pull up in the dialog but pinterest don't execute you're not using clean URL's.

Hope i also made u happy like myself!!!

Cheers its friday and my problems are gone!!

Answer (score 0):

pinterest pinning agent should be:
Pinterest/0.1 +http://pinterest.com/

I'm looking for the pinterest agent that does the preview/url handoff on a click on a pin.  Not sure if it's the same as the agent that does the pin-image grab or not.  Anyone know?  I'm trying to test to see if it's the same, now.

Comment: thanks Grrr, however it didn't solve my problem. The preview dialog is  set trough the user agent and og. metatags i believe. If you have this set up for Facebook already it should be working. Do you know if Pinterest only use clean URL's? (maybe that's my problem)